# Reversing a GMSMutablePath Array

Tags: ios, google-maps, casting

According to the documentation GMSMutablePath is:

```
GMSMutablePath is a dynamic (resizable) array of CLLocationCoordinate2D. [Google Documentation]
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_mutable_path

I want to reverse the order of the Path coordinates. Normally with an Array I would use:

```
[[array123 reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

but none of the NSArray functions will work on it and if I try to cast it to an NSArray or NSMutableArray I just get red flags.

How do I reverse the order of the elements in GMSMutablePath or how do I properly cast it to a NSArray?

Comment: It's not an object inherited from `NSMutableArray`. You can't cast it like that that. Just do it manually, with `replaceCoordinateAtIndex:withCoordinate:` for instance, with a simple for loop.: Maybe like this: `for (NSUInteger i1 = 0; i1 < [myPath count]/2; i1 ++) { NSUInteger i2 =  [myPath count]-i1; CLLocationCoordinate2D *coord1 = [myPath coordinateAtIndex:i1]; CLLocationCoordinate2D *coord2 = [myPath coordinateAtIndex:i2]; [myPath replaceCoordinateAtIndex:i1 withCoordinate:coord2]; [myPath replaceCoordinateAtIndex:i2 withCoordinate:coord1];}`

Comment: @Larme That works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GMSMutablePath` doesn't inherits from `NSMutableArray`, so you can't cast it as a `NSMutableArray`.
What you can do it do it manually. If we wanted to do it with `NSMutableArray` we could call `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:`, but since `GMSMutablePath` doesn't seems to provide an equivalent for that method, we can do it more explictly.

```
for (NSUInteger i1 = 0; i1 < [myPath count]/2; i1 ++)
{
   NSUInteger i2 =  [myPath count]-i1;
   CLLocationCoordinate2D *coord1 = [myPath coordinateAtIndex:i1];
   CLLocationCoordinate2D *coord2 = [myPath coordinateAtIndex:i2];
   [myPath replaceCoordinateAtIndex:i1 withCoordinate:coord2];
   [myPath replaceCoordinateAtIndex:i2 withCoordinate:coord1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code if you want to go one way and the come back the same way.

```
lazy var path : GMSMutablePath = {
    if let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: self.encodedString) {
        let max = path.count()
        for i in 0..<max {
            let reversePos = max-i // reverte the path so you can go and come back the same way
            path.add(path.coordinate(at: reversePos))
        }
        return path
    }
    return GMSMutablePath()
}()
```